# Bind self-insert-command in sparse keymap

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I have a sparse keymap with `suppress-keymap` set as a parent:

```
(setq km (make-sparse-keymap))
(setq skm (make-keymap))
(suppress-keymap skm t)
(set-keymap-parent km skm)
(add-to-list 'emulation-mode-map-alists (list (cons t km)))
```

Desired behavior is to have a limited set of keys bound to `self-insert-command` (insert a key character in current position), and others to be suppressed.
I can achieve this with an anonymous function (first line below) but binding `self-insert-command` directly throws `is undefined` message when key is pressed (second line below).

```
(define-key km (kbd "a") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "a"))) ;; works
(define-key km (kbd "b") #'self-insert-command) ;; throws "b is undefined"
```

Why binding of `self-insert-command` is suppressed in this example?

Comment: Why do you say you can't bind it? Always specify what you mean - what behavior do you see and what did you expect to see instead. Just saying that something doesn't work doesn't tell us what that means.

Comment: @Drew edited question

Comment: Thx. Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? (I don't see it.) If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: @Drew, the binding of 'b' doesn't throw an error, but typing 'b' does in `emacs-27 -Q` at least

Comment: I use Emacs 28 with `-Q` argument. It doesn't throw error, just says that `b is undefined`

Comment: I've never used `emulation-mode-map-alists`, but from a quick look at the doc I'm guessing this is maybe what you want instead: `(add-to-list 'emulation-mode-map-alists (cons t km))`.

Comment: @Drew `emulation-mode-map-alists` part works fine. I use it like this in my `multistate` package. Besides, other keys wouldn't throw `is undefined` if keymap wasn't setup properly.